# How do i get my input value from one method to print in another method, ive looked all over the site and nothings worked

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, methods

I'm trying to get my input from `int stuScore=keyboard.nextInt();` in the `populateTestScores` method into the `printStudentReport` method without using a class. I have an attachment of how its supposed to look in a link at the end.

Can anyone help me out?

```
 public static void populateTestScores(String[]names,int[][]scores)
 {
    for(int stuNames = 0; stuNames < names.length; stuNames++)
    {
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Entering scores for " + names[stuNames] +":" );

        for(int testNum=0; testNum<scores[0].length; testNum++)
        {

            System.out.print("Enter score for test #" + (testNum+1) + ":" );
            int stuScore=keyboard.nextInt();

        }
        System.out.println();
     }
}

public static void printStudentReport(String[]names,int[][]scores)
{
    System.out.println("Student Report");
    System.out.println();
    for(int stuNames = 0; stuNames < names.length; stuNames++)
    {
        System.out.println("Scores for " + names[stuNames] +":" );

        for(int testNum=0; testNum<scores[0].length; testNum++)
        {
           System.out.println("Test " + (testNum+1) + ":" + scores[stuNames][testNum] );

        }
        System.out.println();
     }
}
```

this is what it needs to print http://jonlebeau.com/courses/244/StuTest.Output.txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be a comment instead of an answer but i dont have the reputation for that.

- you are providing the populate method with a `scores` array. This can work when you have an enclosing class that keeps that array as a field, which the print method can access.

As i understand, you don't want to use a class that encapsulates these 2 methods, so i suggest you to initialize the `scores` inside the populate method and make the populate method return the `scores` . the response can then be used to pass to the printer method when running the

hope this helps, Feel free to ask!

Comment: so when i get my return value for  'stuScores' how do i get it to print in the next method without it creating an error? @chaixdev

Answer (score 0):

You can call the method

```
printStudentReport(String[]names,int[][]scores)
```

like

```
printStudentReport(String[]names,int[][]scores, int stuScore)
```

from populateTestScores method.

But according to your sample output the printStudentReport method should execute after populateTestScores has executed (for the flow of the output)

So I suggest creating a data structure (array, list etc) to store all the stuScores (in populateTestScores as you are already looping through it) and sent the data structure to printStudentReport like and print it with the for loop again.

```
printStudentReport(String[]names,int[][]scores, data Structure type stuScore)
```

I also suggest you consider complexity in theses cases. See if you can minimize the for loop into one.

Answer (score 0):

Method to collect data using scanner:

```
private static void populateTestScores(){
  Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

  System.out.println("Enter number of tests:");
  noOfTests = scan.nextInt();

  System.out.println("Enter number of students:");
  noOfStudents = scan.nextInt();

  List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();

  for (int i = 0; i < noOfStudents; i++) {
    System.out.println("Enter student "+ (i + 1) +" name:");
    names.add(scan.next());
  }

  for (String name: names) {
    System.out.println("Entering scores for " + name + ":");
    List<Integer> marks = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < noOfTests; i++) {
      System.out.println("Enter score for test #" + (i + 1) +":");
      marks.add(scan.nextInt());
    }
    studentMarks.put(name, marks);
  }
}
```

Method to Print Student Report:

```
private static void printStudentReport(){
  System.out.println("STUDENT REPORT");
  System.out.println(noOfStudents + " student(s) took " + noOfTests + " test(s).");
  for (String name : studentMarks.keySet()) {
    System.out.println("Entering scores for " + name);
    List<Integer> marks = studentMarks.get(name);
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < noOfTests; i++) {
      System.out.println("\tEnter score for test #" + (i + 1) + " : " + marks.get(i));
      sum += marks.get(i);
    }
    System.out.println("\tAverage for " + name + " : " + sum / noOfTests);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can go with the below solution to achieve this output.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class School {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter number of student(s) : ");
        int studentCount = input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter test count : ");
        int testCount = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("\n" + studentCount + " student(s) took " + testCount + " test(s)\n");
        List<Student> studentList = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 1; i <= studentCount; i++) {
            System.out.print("Enter student " + i + " name: ");
            Scanner nameInput = new Scanner(System.in);
            String studentName = nameInput.nextLine();
            Student student = new Student();
            student.setName(studentName);
            studentList.add(student);
        }

        System.out.println("\n");

        for (Student student : studentList) {
            System.out.println("Entering scores for " + student.getName() + ":");
            for (int i = 1; i <= testCount; i++) {
                System.out.print("\tEnter score for test #" + i + ": ");
                Scanner scoreInput = new Scanner(System.in);
                int score = scoreInput.nextInt();
                student.getTest().add(score);
            }
        }

        System.out.println("\nSTUDENT REPORT");

        for (Student student : studentList) {
            System.out.println("Scores for " + student.getName() + ":");
            int total = 0;
            for (int i = 1; i <= student.getTest().size(); i++) {
                int temp = i - 1;
                total = total + student.getTest().get(temp);
                System.out.println("\tTest #" + i + ": " + student.getTest().get(temp));
            }
            double temp = (double) total / student.getTest().size();
            double avg = (double) Math.round(temp * 100) / 100;
            System.out.println("\tAverage for " + student.getName() + ": " + avg);
        }
    }

}


class Student {

    private String name;

    private List<Integer> test = new ArrayList<>();

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public List<Integer> getTest() {
        return test;
    }

    public void setTest(List<Integer> test) {
        this.test = test;
    }
}
```

and below is the output :

```
Enter number of student(s) : 5
Enter test count : 2

5 student(s) took 2 test(s)

Enter student 1 name: A
Enter student 2 name: B
Enter student 3 name: C
Enter student 4 name: D
Enter student 5 name: E


Entering scores for A:
    Enter score for test #1: 12
    Enter score for test #2: 11
Entering scores for B:
    Enter score for test #1: 14
    Enter score for test #2: 15
Entering scores for C:
    Enter score for test #1: 12
    Enter score for test #2: 13
Entering scores for D:
    Enter score for test #1: 14
    Enter score for test #2: 15
Entering scores for E:
    Enter score for test #1: 11
    Enter score for test #2: 12

STUDENT REPORT
Scores for A:
    Test #1: 12
    Test #2: 11
    Average for A: 11.5
Scores for B:
    Test #1: 14
    Test #2: 15
    Average for B: 14.5
Scores for C:
    Test #1: 12
    Test #2: 13
    Average for C: 12.5
Scores for D:
    Test #1: 14
    Test #2: 15
    Average for D: 14.5
Scores for E:
    Test #1: 11
    Test #2: 12
    Average for E: 11.5
```